# How to pass 2 or more arguments from HTML inputs to a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, input, arguments

I have these inputs:

```
<input type='radio' id='1' name='s' onclick='pieces(this.value);'  value='6'>6
<input type='radio' id='2' name='s' onclick='pieces(this.value);'  value='12'>12
<input type='radio' id='3' name='s' onclick='pieces(this.value);'  value='24'>24
<input type='radio' id='11' name='v' onclick='pieces(this.value);'  value='yes'>Yes
<input type='radio' id='12' name='v' onclick='pieces(this.value);'  value='no'>No
```

I want to pass the value from "name='s'" to var1, and value from "name='v'" to var2 to the function `pieces(var1, var2)` when the radio button is clicked.

Comment: @arttronics, already editted. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get values of both radio inputs in Javascript method itself using `document.getElementsByName()` method or this should also work,
Try using `func(document.getElementsByName('s'),document.getElementsByName('v'))`

Below code should help,

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="js1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('Ok');
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        var r1=$('input:radio[name=s]').val();
        var r2=$('input:radio[name=v]').val();
        show(r1,r2);
    });
});

function show(r1,r2){
    alert(r1);
    alert(r2);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='radio' id='1' name='s' onclick='pieces(this.value);'  value='6'>6
<input type='radio' id='2' name='s' onclick='pieces(this.value);'  value='12'>12
<input type='radio' id='3' name='s' onclick='pieces(this.value);'  value='24'>24


<input type='radio' id='11' name='v' onclick='pieces(this.value);'  value='yes'>Yes
<input type='radio' id='12' name='v' onclick='pieces(this.value);'  value='no'>No

<button id="btn">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can change show function to get values there also as shown below,     function show(){
  var r1=$('input:radio[name=s]').val();
  var r2=$('input:radio[name=v]').val();
  alert(r1);
  alert(r2);
 }

Comment: why that code doesn't work, i applied that to ajax and it seems like only the 1st variable (r1) got value.

xmlhttp.open('GET','url.php?a1='+r1+'&a2='+r2,true);

Comment: @ivory-santos, this particular Answer requires that you choose two radio buttons as nothing is set from the beginning. Check out the previous comment with the jsFiddle I provided. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the arguments in the following different ways:

```
function antguider(name, url){
    alert("Name = "+name+" URL = "+url);
}
```

HTML Part

```
<input type="button" onclick=antguider('AntGuider','http://antguider.blogspot.com') value="Click Without Quotation" />
<input type="button" onclick="antguider('AntGuider','http://antguider.blogspot.com')" value="Click With Quotation" />
<input type="button" onclick="antguider(12345,'http://antguider.blogspot.com')" value="No Quotation Needed For Button" />
```

Comment: You are missing double quotes for the first onclick attribute. This markup will not [**validate**](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) and can cause parsing issues.

Comment: If you have reference to using `onclick` in element tag without quotation for first `input button`, please provided it. Thank you.

Comment: In an HTML attribute without Quotation also work.   Quotation is used to group. Example) title="Click Event" will work and         title=Click Event will take the first value(Click) only. That is if a word doesn't contains space then no need of Quotation.

Comment: Why then does your non-spaced onclick fail W3C validation? Ok, I just found a great article that describes your Answer and why it fails validation. **+1** for a great answer! Reference: [**article**](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/qattr.html)

Comment: It is not a correct way to use like that. But it is working in all the Major Browsers.

Comment: Yes, in this case it's the fault of W3C. Thank you!

Comment: I edit your Answer with a HTML Comment so future SO Members will not edit this first `onclick` attribute. Nice lesson today!

Answer (score 0):

For 2 inputs, this can easily be done with JQuery.

```
va1=$("input[name=s]").val();
va2=$("input[name=v]").val();
```

Then call the desired function, passing in your values as parameters.

```
func(va1,va2);
```